# Shiny- CSS working locally but not correctly when deployed

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am facing a problem with CSS using R's shiny app library. I include HTML and a CSS file and locally it works perfectly (also in the browser), but when deployed (on both shiny server as well as my own server) some structures are destroyed, even though some parts of the CSS are still working correctly.

This is how it looks like when deployed.

[image: When deployed]

This is how it looks locally.

[image: Locally]

This is my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  navbarPage("Peter Dieter",position = c("fixed-top"),
             tabPanel("Welcome!",
                      includeHTML("Welcomepage.html"),
                      HTML(paste0('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/badges/js/profile.js" async defer></script>
                                  <div class="LI-profile-badge"  data-version="v1" data-size="medium" data-locale="de_DE" data-type="vertical" data-theme="dark" data-vanity="peter-dieter"><a class="LI-simple-link" href="https://de.linkedin.com/in/peter-dieter?trk=profile-badge">Peter Dieter</a></div>'))
                      ),
             tabPanel("My CV", 
                      includeHTML("srt-resume2.html")
             ),
             tabPanel("Projects",
                      includeHTML("Projects.html")
             ),
             tabPanel("Stats Game",
                      includeHTML("statsgamehtml.html"),
                      absolutePanel(actionButton("new","New Game"),top = "210px",left="200px"),
                      absolutePanel(sliderInput("inp","Pearson Correlation",min=-1,max=1,value = 0,step=0.01),top = "280px",left="100px"),
                      absolutePanel(plotOutput("dataplot"),top = "170px",left="520px",width = "500px"),
                      absolutePanel(actionButton("answer","Check Answer"),top = "460px",left="200px"),
                      useShinyalert()
             )
             ),

  includeCSS("resume.css"),
  setBackgroundColor(color=c("#2980B9","#6DD5FA"),gradient = c("radial"),direction = "right")
  )#
```

Comment: Hoe exactly are you deploying it? Are there any errors in the web browser that can give a clue to what might be wrong (like files that it can't find)? Maybe it can't find the css file?

Comment: First I deployed it on the shiny server, then on my own server, both times i uploaded all relevant files. I even tried to add the CSS code directly in the file (which is possible in shiny) and I had the same problem. Also, deleting the CSS file does result in an error, so it must have find it.

Comment: Load the deployed page and check the Developer Tool console for any errors with finding JS and CSS files and other references.

Comment: @DriveItLikeYouStoleIt Yes thank you, there are some errors found, I will first try to solve them myself. But that must be it